# Fatal Exception Main on a null object reference

Tags: android, kotlin, fatal-error

I have an error when I click to see the details of some of my pokemon. He is getting null reference, but I don't know how to solve it so as not to crash. Can someone help me?

Log Error:

> ```
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.pokedex, PID: 28852
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object 
> java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object reference
>     at 
>
>
>
>   com.example.pokedex.ui.detalhesPokemons.
>   DetalhesPokemonsFragment$configDetalhes$$inlined$observe$1.onChan 
>   ged(LiveData.kt:58)
>     at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify(LiveData.java:133)
>     at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue(LiveData.java:151)
>     at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.setValue(LiveData.java:309)
>     at androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData.setValue(MutableLiveData.java:50)
>     at 
>  com.example.pokedex.ui.detalhesPokemons.DetalhesPokemonsViewModel$getDetalhes$1.
>  invokeSuspend(DetalhesPokemonsViewModel.kt:20)
>     at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
>     at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
>     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
> ```

```
class DetalhesFragmentPokemon

     private val detalhesViewModel: DetalhesPokemonsViewModel by viewModels{
        DetalhesPokemonsViewModelFactory((activity?.application as MyApplication).repository)
    }
    private val argumentos by navArgs<DetalhesPokemonsFragmentArgs>()
    private val pokemon by lazy { argumentos.pokemon }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
         ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.detalhes_pokemon,
            container,
            false
        )

    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        configDetalhes()
    }

    private fun configDetalhes() {
       detalhesViewModel.getDetalhes(pokemon.id)
        detalhesViewModel.mResponse.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
            if (it.isSuccessful) {
                tv_detalhes_nome_pokemon.text = pokemon.nome
                tv_detalhes_habilidades_pokemon.text = pokemon.abilities[0].name
                tv_hp_detalhes_pokemon.text = pokemon.hp

        })
    }
```

```
class DetalhesPokemonsViewModel(

    private val repository: PokedexRepository
    ): ViewModel() {
        val mResponse: MutableLiveData<Response<PokemonItem>> = 
    MutableLiveData()

        fun getDetalhes(id: String){
            viewModelScope.launch {
                val response = repository.getPokemonsDetalhes(id)
                mResponse.value = response
            }
        }
    }
```

Can someone help me? I couldn't fix this error, because it only happens in some cases.

I added the DetalhesPokemonViewModel class, which is where I think the problem lies

Comment: It looks like you have some list not initialized, can't say for sure without seeing view model, but from what I see here `pokemon.abilities` might be the reason

Comment: @YaroslavShulyak I added the ViewModel, please see if you can help me

Comment: Ah, it seems you getting pokemon object from arguments, and it might have null abilities list, but you probably want to use 'it' inside callback instead. Check if it's null with logs or debugger

Comment: @YaroslavShulyak I made a debug and the app is crashing in the function "configDetalhes". I don't know what to do to make it receive a null value